# nginx on ubuntu: restrict access to .PHP within public directory?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx

I am quite new to linux and nginx in general, how can I prevent direct user access to one of my .PHP files that is located under /www/ folder?

I am running nginx and php-fpm on linux ubuntu.

I tried .htaccess but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: show some current config and what you want to exclude. .htaccess is for **apache**

Comment: I have file called validate.php within www directory. 
When user enters login and password, it does ajax call to check if user is valid or not, it returns true or false. 

I don't want people to use some kind of brute force to send requests to validate.php waiting for server to return true thus making the login and password valid and gaining access to website.

Comment: For example you can specify a location and only allow a specific IP address. Or something like that.

Comment: Have a look here: http://2levelsabove.com/how-to-secure-an-nginx-server-with-fail2ban/ and http://serverfault.com/questions/421046/how-to-limit-nginx-auth-basic-re-tries maybe you can find something useful